# How to merge the keys from two different arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

So I have two arrays. My main one is stored in a variable called `$topVideos` looks like this:

```
["rows"] => array(10) {
    [0] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(11) "GARuSV" 
        [1] => float(2003)
    }
    [1] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(11) "rDnbeSrk" 
        [1] => float(1119)
    }
    [2] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(11) "0ykEqaUI" 
        [1] => float(1015)
    }
```

And the second one is stored in a variable called `$titles` and looks like this:

```
array(10) {
    [0] => string(25) "Serve Heroes" 
    [1] => string(38) "Rover Sailing Adventure!!" 
    [2] => string(54) "BNI Presentation"
```

What I have to do is merge the second one's every key into the first one's, so it can look like this:

```
["rows"] => array(10) {
        [0] => array(2) {
            [0] => string(11) "GARuSV" 
            [1] => float(2003)
            [3] => string(25) "Serve Heroes" 
        }
        [1] => array(2) {
            [0] => string(11) "rDnbeSrk" 
            [1] => float(1119)
            [3] => string(25) "Rover Sailing Adventure!!" 
        }
        [2] => array(2) {
            [0] => string(11) "0ykEqaUI" 
            [1] => float(1015)
            [3] => string(25) "BNI Presentation" 
        }
```

How can I accomplish this? Any help is welcomed! Thank you for your time

Comment: Come on... You can figure that out yourself...

Comment: $a + $b for arrays actually work in PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($titles as $key => $title){
    $topVideos["rows"][$key][] = $title;
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer that works (I tested them all).

Comment: Thank you for your time! This is the solution to my problem!

Comment: A little side-note: if the `$key` doesn't exist in `$topVideos['row']` you will get a notice. Unless your sure that this will **never** be the case I would change the second line to `if( isset($topVideos["rows"][$key]) ) { $topVideos["rows"][$key][] = $title; }`. Just a little check that will prevent a notice...

Comment: @LinkinTED yeah, you are right, but not completely - `titles` may contain items, which keys are not identical with `$topVideos["rows"]` array, but they should be merged

Answer (score 0):

Loop the array, check if the value exists in the other array, if so, add it.

```
<?php
foreach( $topVideos['rows'] as $i => $v ) {
   if( isset( $titles[$i] ) ) { $topVideos['rows'][$i][] = $titles[$i]; }
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you test it? I tested it and it does nothing.

Comment: You've missed `"rows"` flag for array `$topVideos` in line 2, column 42

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez, thank you for the notice. Instead of criticizing answers I would rather see that you help looking for the answer to someone's question... but hey that's just my opinion.

Comment: I tell people when their answers don't work so they can fix them before they get downvoted.

Comment: Yeah, me too, but instead of only commenting that it doesn't work, I give them the solution as well (as Mark Anderson did too)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_merge_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) to get the desired result

```
$array = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
```

Comment: I tested it and it doesn't work, the second array is **appended**.